# Construction of Tensor Product of Functors

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $D$ is cocomplete, $S:C^{op}\rightarrow Set$ and $T:C\rightarrow D$ are functors. Then, I know that the tensor product of $S$ and $T$ is defined to be the coend $\int ^{c}Sc\cdot Tc$, which exists because $C$ is cocomplete. But I have not seen an explicit construction, from scratch so I want to do it myself.

Here is an outline of my attempt. My question is whether I am on the right track and if not, where I should be going.

$(1)$. Define $F:C^{op}\times C\rightarrow D $ by $F(c,c')=\coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc'$.

Define $F$ on arrows as follows:

If $f:d\rightarrow c$ and $g:c'\rightarrow d'$ then we need an arrow

$\coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{k\in Sd}Td'$

Consider the commuting square

\begin{matrix}Tc' &\stackrel{Tg}{\rightarrow}&Td'\\\downarrow{\beta_{Sf(k)}}&&\downarrow{\lambda _k}\\ \coprod _{\left \{ i\in Sc:Sf(k)=i \right \}}Tc'& \stackrel{\phi }{\rightarrow}&\coprod _{_{k\in Sd}}Td'\end{matrix}

where $\lambda _k$ and $\beta _{Sf(k)}$ are the usual coproduct injections and $\phi $ is the unique arrow provided by the UMP of the coproduct.

We also have a unique $\psi :\coprod _{\left \{ i\in Sc\right \}}Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{\left \{ i\in Sc:Sf(k)=i \right \}}Tc'$ such that $\psi \circ \beta_i=\beta_{Sf(k)}$

We set $F(f,g)=\phi \circ \psi$.

Of course, one has to show $F$ is a functor.

$(2)$ Suppose $f:c'\rightarrow c$.  Then, with arrows $h_c:\coprod _{k\in Sc}Tc,\rightarrow \coprod _{c\in C}\left ( \coprod _{k\in Sc}Tc \right )$ the coproduct injections, we have the square
\begin{matrix}\coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc' &\stackrel{F(1,f)}{\rightarrow}&\coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc\\\downarrow{F(f,1)}&&\downarrow{h_c}\\\coprod _{k\in Sc'}Tc'& \stackrel{h_{c'}}{\rightarrow}&\coprod _{c\in C}\left ( \coprod _{k\in Sc}Tc \right )\end{matrix}.

and the following data:

$\lambda _{k}:Tc\rightarrow \coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc$

$\beta _{k}:Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc'$

$\lambda ' _{k}:Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{k\in Sc'}Tc'$

$F(f,1)=\phi _1:\coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{k\in Sc'}Tc$

$F(1,f)=\phi : \coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc'\rightarrow \coprod _{i\in Sc}Tc$

and the conditions:

$\phi \circ \beta _k=\lambda _k \circ Tf$ and $\phi _1 \circ \beta _k= \lambda '_k$

For the square to commute we would require

$h_c \circ \phi =h_{c'}\circ \phi _1$ which I think means either that one must take a quotient of $C$ or find a coequalizer for a certain pair of maps. On the other hand, if $C$ is not small then $\coprod _{c\in C}\left ( \coprod _{k\in Sc}Tc \right )$ doesn't even make sense so maybe this is the wrong approach altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track; I think there is no particular problem in resolving size issues embedding everything in a suitably large universe, so that all boils down to the verification of the initial cowedge condition for the family
$$
\left\{Sx \cdot Tx \xrightarrow{\omega_x} \int^c Sc \cdot Tc\right\}_{x\in \cal C}
$$
Once you are convinced of this, it is possible to take a more conceptual point of view: first of all, recall that an *adjunctions of two variables* is a triple $\mathfrak t=\{\otimes , \wedge, [-,=]\}$ of (bi)functors between three categories $\mathbf{S}, \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$, defined via the adjunctions
$$
\hom_{\mathbf{B}}(S\otimes A, B)\cong \hom_{\mathbf{S}}(S, [A,B])\cong \hom_{\mathbf{A}}(A, S\land B).
$$ 
Such an isomorphism uniquely determines the domains ant the variance of the three functors involved, in each variable, but to be clear $\otimes \colon \mathbf{S}\times \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{B}$, and then $\land \colon \mathbf{S}^\text{op}\times \mathbf{B}\to \mathbf{A}$, and $[-,=] \colon \mathbf{A}^\text{op}\times \mathbf{B}\to \mathbf{S}$. The prototype of this situation is the tensor, hom, cotensor functors of a suitably nice monoidal category, or the copower, hom, and power of a co/tensored enriched category.

Now, given an adjunction of three variables $\mathfrak t$, one can induce *another* adjunction of three variables $\mathfrak{t}' = \{\boxtimes, \curlywedge, \langle-,=\rangle \}$, on the categories $\mathbf{S}^{\mathbf{I}^\text{op}\times \mathbf{J}}, \mathbf{A}^\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{B}^\mathbf{J}$, for any $\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{J}\in\mathbf{Cat}$; to see this, start defining $F\boxtimes G\in \mathbf{B}^\mathbf{J}$ out of $F\in \mathbf{S}^{\mathbf{I}^\text{op}\times \mathbf{J}}, G\in \mathbf{A}^\mathbf{I}$, as the coend 
$$
\int^i F(i, -)\otimes Gi
$$
It is an instructive exercise in coend calculus to show that this induces suitable functors $\curlywedge$ and $\langle -,=\rangle$: for example
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{B}^\mathbf{J}(F\boxtimes G,H) & \cong \int_j \mathbf{B}((F\boxtimes G)j, Hj)\\
& \cong \int_j \mathbf{B}\left(\int^i F(i,j)\otimes Gi, Hj\right)\\
& \cong \int_{ij} \mathbf{B}( F(i,j)\otimes Gi, Hj)\\
& \cong \int_{ij} \mathbf{A}(Gi, F(i,j)\land Hj)\\
& \cong \int_{i} \mathbf{A}\left(Gi, \int_j F(i,j)\land Hj\right)\\
& \cong \mathbf{A}^\mathbf{I}(G, F\curlywedge H)
\end{align*}$$
if we define $F\curlywedge H\colon i\mapsto \int_j F(i,j)\land Hj$.

Do the other as an exercise!

Comment: Thanks for a very clear and concise exposition. I have always thought that the $\hom-\text{tensor}$ adjunction was just a "fancy Currying" but now I see that the idea extends to a much more general setting. I know the $\hom-\text{tensor}$ adjunction is used to reduce dealing with certain structures to looking at homsets, which are easer, but is there an easy example of how inducing an adjunction in the three new variables used?

Comment: Also, I have not been able to show that my square commutes. I think I need to take a quotient of $C$ or perhaps take the coequalizer of all the $h_c\circ \phi ,h_{c'}\circ \phi _1$ so it would be a collection indexed by $c\in C$ and $\left \{ f:c'\rightarrow c \right \}_{\left \{ f\in ArrC \right \}}$

Comment: Doing that coequalizer is precisely the way the coend is constructed out of the definition: you have to coequalize the diagram
$$
\coprod_{c\to c'} Sc'\cdot Tc \rightrightarrows \coprod_{c\in \cal C} Sc \cdot Tc
$$